# How to use Chart.js bar graph to show MYSQL data without PHP

Tags: mysql, chart.js

I'm building a project to use Chart.js to build bar graphs to show MYSQL data without using PHP. Any help with a sample code?

I connected to MYSQL data
I created a results object
In Chart.js I set labels to results object
No results are shown

Comment: Without any code it's difficult to answer/help.